# RestTemplate logging interceptor + Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I've created a `RestTemplate` interceptor (`ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`) to log requests and responses and enabled Spring Cloud Sleuth with the goal of tracing transactions from when the interceptor receives a request to the point where it returns a result. However, Sleuth's trace and span ids do not appear in the interceptors log messages; it seems they are only at a later stage in processing the request. I would like to be able to trace into services that do not have explicit logging, so the interceptor seemed like a good approach, but if there is no way to add the trace and span ids at this stage then I may need to find another approach.  Looking for any suggestion which would either add the trace and span to the interceptors log messages or another way to log requests and responses across services with trace and span ids.  Thanks!

**EDIT**: Here's an example of the log output I'm currently getting from my `RestTemplate` interceptor with Spring Cloud Sleuth enabled:

```
2020-08-21 18:53:17.164 DEBUG [,,,] 14256 --- [           main] .c.o.l.RequestResponseLoggingInterceptor : ⇒ HTTP REQUEST: METHOD 'POST', URI 'http://localhost:59742/….
```

What I'd really like to get is the request (or repsonse) logged with the Sleuth `trace` and `span` ids:

```
2020-08-21 18:53:17.164 DEBUG [my-service-name,d3cb8a2fa7d1d9ac,80b023cb829bf254,false] 14256 --- [           main] .c.o.l.RequestResponseLoggingInterceptor : ⇒ HTTP REQUEST: METHOD 'POST', URI 'http://localhost:59742/….
```

I'm wondering whether this is possible (ie, adding logging to all service through a `RestTemplate` interceptor *and* having those log messages contain the Sleuth ids) or whether there is a different approach I should take to log all requests and responses with the Sleuth trace/span ids.  I would appreciate any suggestions!

**EDIT 2**: A bit more information...My Sleuth config at this point is nothing more than enabling it in a `bootstrap.yml` file:

```
spring:
    cloud:
        sleuth:
            enabled: true
```

I also created / configured a custom `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`, which executes just after the interceptor (it's the next line in the log) and *does* have the trace / span ids in its log message:

```
2020-08-21 18:53:17.164 DEBUG [my-app,d3cb8a2fa7d1d9ac,80b023cb829bf254,false] 3479 --- [c-auto-1-exec-2] c.t.c.o.l.CustomRequestLoggingFilter  : ⇒ POST ...
```

So Sleuth seems to be configured correctly (at least for my purposes now); it just isn't adding the trace ids to the interceptor's log messages.
Thanks!

Comment: Theoretical questions are hard to answer. Share the code, your observations and your expectated output clearly to get better community support.

Comment: I've updated the question with examples of the current log output from the RestTemplate interceptor and what I'd like to see (same output-- log of the request or response-- with the Sleuth trace and span ids).

Comment: Have you added sleuth to your classpath or as dependency?

Comment: Yes. Sleuth is working, just not at the point of the interceptor-- log messages _after_ the request is logged by the interceptor, and all of those _before_ the response is logged all have the trace and span ids. They are just not appearing in the interceptor's log messages. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @TimothyPerrigo, could you please help me to write the ClientHttpRequestInterceptor. I have similar activity. Could you please share some insights or code sample to write that piece of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleuth documentation says

> You have to register RestTemplate as a bean so that the interceptors will get injected. If you create a RestTemplate instance with a new keyword then the instrumentation WILL NOT work.

I hope you are not using `new` keyword to instantiate RestTemplate.

Comment: No, not using `new`; the template is registered as a bean and managed by the container.

Comment: Please share how you have setup sleuth in your project.

Comment: Additional info added in message. Thanks!

Comment: **Update**: I stand corrected, and I wanted to correct my responses. Upon further investigation, another library my app is using _was_ creating a `RestTemplate` using `new`. After removing this, my interceptor's log messages contain the Sleuth trace and span ids, as expected.